# AWS: VPC interface endpoint for private subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc, subnet

I have 3 private subnets (internet access through NAT gateways). I would like to leverage [VPC endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/endpoint-services-overview.html) to interact with AWS services like SQS, SNS, RDS etc from these subnets without accessing the internet (all traffic for these services should remain inside AWS).
The problem is, when I try to create a VPC endpoint for example for a service like SQS, I can only choose type `interface` which seems to support only public subnets:

[image]

But I need to use the VPC endpoint inside private subnets (without an IGW).
Is this possible?

Comment: What did you try and what problem did you face? I was able to do it (see below), so just wondering what you did differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reproduce this situation I did the following:

- Created a VPC
- Created 4 subnets in the VPC:

  - Public in AZ-A
  - Public in AZ-B
  - Private in AZ-A
  - Private in AZ-B

I then went to create a VPC Endpoints for Amazon SQS and I was able to select *any* of the subnets:

[image: Creating a VPC Endpoint]

Comment: You are right, I've completely missed the dropdown menu where I can select a different subnet for that specific AZ